# Android Device mock location provider for Gmaps

Tags: android, gps

I need to fool GMap application on android device by providing my own positioning data.
What is the possibility and how shall i go about achieving it?

Thanks,
Black

Answer (score 0):

First way is to download a free aplication and use that to mock the location of your phone the app is [Location Spoofer](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/location-spoofer_gkmc.html). This is good for presentation purposes.

The second way is to create your own mock location provider see this [tutorial](http://diffract.me/2009/11/android-location-provider-mock/)